# Editing a record: conflict between props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When editing a record, the data being displayed on the component belongs to the props. I get an error

> Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of `TerritoryDetail`.

I have a feeling I implemented my edit record component the wrong way based on what the docs say involving [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

When editing a record, should you not use props for the field values? If that is the case, I have values of the record in my application state, but how do I sync my application state to my component state without using props?

In addition, the props say what value the select option should be on edit. But component state is used to monitor changes in the select option. How would component state update the props of the record, when the props are being set by application state and not component state?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTerritory, getTerritoryMetaData, updateTerritory, modal } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import TerritoryTabs from './territory-tabs';

class TerritoryDetail extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.openSearchUserQueueModal = this.openSearchUserQueueModal.bind(this);
    this.setAssignedToType = this.setAssignedToType.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    // console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getTerritory(this.props.params.id);
    this.props.getTerritoryMetaData();
  }

  renderTerritoryPickList(fieldName) {
    return this.props.territoryFields.map((territoryField) => {
      const shouldRender = territoryField.name === fieldName;
      if (shouldRender) {
      return territoryField.picklistValues.map((option) => {
          return<option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>;
      });
    }
    });
  }

  setAssignedToType(event) {
    this.setState({ assignedToType : event.target.value });
  }

  openSearchUserQueueModal(searchType) {
    this.props.modal({
      type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
      modalType: 'USER_QUEUE_SEARCH',
      modalProps: {searchType}
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Update button being clicked');
    this.props.updateTerritory({
        Name: this.refs[ `Name`].value,
        tpslead__Type__c: this.refs[ `tpslead__Type__c`].value,
        tpslead__Assigned_To_Type__c: this.refs[ `tpslead__Assigned_To_Type__c`].value,
        tpslead__Assigned_To__c: this.refs['tpslead__Assigned_To__c'].value,
        tpslead__Assigned_To_ID__c: this.refs['tpslead__Assigned_To_ID__c'].value
      }, this.props.params.id);
  }

  onChangeTerritoryName(event) {
    this.props.
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.props.territory) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return(
      <TerritoryTabs id={this.props.params.id} listTab="detail">
        <div className="slds-form">
              <div className="slds-form-element">
            <div className="slds-form-element__label">
                  <label className="slds-align-middle" htmlFor="input1">Lead Territory Name</label>
            </div>
            <div className="slds-form-element__control">
                  <input type="text" ref="Name" className="slds-input" value={this.props.territory.Name}/>
            </div>
          </div>
              <div className="slds-form-element">
                <label className="slds-form-element__label" htmlFor="input2">Type</label>
                <div className="slds-form-element__control">
                    <div className="slds-select_container">
                        <select ref="tpslead__Type__c" className="slds-select" value={this.props.territory.tpslead__Type__c}>
                    <option></option>
                    {this.renderTerritoryPickList('tpslead__Type__c')}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="slds-form-element">
                <label className="slds-form-element__label" htmlFor="input3">Assigned to Type</label>
                <div className="slds-form-element__control">
                    <div className="slds-select_container">
                        <select ref="tpslead__Assigned_To_Type__c" onChange={ this.setAssignedToType } className="slds-select" value={this.props.territory.tpslead__Assigned_To_Type__c}>
                            <option></option>
                    {this.renderTerritoryPickList('tpslead__Assigned_To_Type__c')}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="slds-form-element">
                <label className="slds-form-element__label">Assigned To</label>
                <div className="slds-form-element__control">
              <section className="slds-clearfix">
              <input ref="tpslead__Assigned_To__c" value={this.props.territory.tpslead__Assigned_To__c} className="slds-input slds-float--left" style={{maxWidth: '95%'}} disabled/>
              <input ref="tpslead__Assigned_To_ID__c" value={this.props.territory.tpslead__Assigned_To_ID__c} type="hidden" />
              <button onClick={this.openSearchUserQueueModal.bind(this, this.props.territory.tpslead__Assigned_To_Type__c)} className="slds-button slds-button--icon-border slds-float--right" aria-live="assertive" style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                <svg className="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlinkHref={searchIcon}></use>
                </svg>
              </button>
              </section>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="slds-form-element slds-p-top--small">
            <Link to="/" className="slds-button slds-button--neutral">
              Cancel
            </Link>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.onSubmit} className="slds-button slds-button--brand">Update</button>
              </div>
        </div>
      </TerritoryTabs>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
console.log(state);

  return { territory: state.territories.single,
           territoryFields: state.territories.fields
         };

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTerritoryMetaData, getTerritory, updateTerritory, modal })(TerritoryDetail);
```

Answer (score 4):

A controlled component means that you've provided both a value and an `onChange` handler. You have to have both, or React will complain. This is also true if you pass a `null` or `undefined` value, so you'll want to default to an empty string in those cases. Example:

```
export function TerritorySelect({ territory = '', options, onChange }) {
  const choices = options.map((o, i) => (
    <option key={i} value={o.value}>{o.label}</option>
  ));

  const update = e => onChange(e.target.value);

  return (
    <select value={territory} onChange={update}>
      {choices}
    </select>
  );
}

export default connect(
  state => ({ territory: state.territory.get('territory') }),
  { onChange: actions.updateTerritory }
)(TerritorySelect)
```

Answer (score 0):

Golden rule is that if the data will be changed by user's input then use the state, otherwise use props. To avoid confusion between application state and component state, I will call application state Redux store.

You can pass whatever is in your Redux store, with the function you already have `mapStateToProps` and on the constructor of your component simply setting them to the state. But the props are always needed, just not in the way you are using it. To do that on the constructor method, just add the following:

```
this.state = {
  // whatever you want to define goes here
  // if you want to pass props you don't need to call this, just props.foo
}
```

That means that you can handle the state of your select and the state of your inputs without an issue.

Your props will be updated whenever they receive new props as long as they are not received by user interaction. That means that you can use your Redux store to dispatch actions, what will fire an update to your props.